# MySQL rejects INSERT INTO if SELECT returns nothing

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, insert-update

I have a table `links` with the columns id, url, url_hash and parent_id (and many more without relevance for my question). I have 2 variables in my code, $url and $parentUrl which may refers to an existing row in `links` table or not. So I want to set parent_id to the id of the first link whose url matches $parentUrl or to set it to 0 or null if there is no parent.

```
INSERT INTO `links` (`url`, `url_hash`, `parent_id`)
SELECT               $url,  MD5(url),   `id`
FROM `links`
WHERE `url` = $parentUrl
LIMIT 1
```

But this fails if the select statement returns 0 rows. I'd like my query to just insert a new row based on the const values (url, url_hash).

```
INSERT INTO `links` (`url`, `url_hash`, `parent_id`)
VALUES              ($url,  MD5(url), ((SELECT `id` FROM `links` WHERE `url`=$parentUrl LIMIT 1))
```

Tried this one too, but this seems to fail with this error:

```
You can't specify target table 'links' for update in FROM clause
```

I do all this to avoid my current, working solution that uses two queries. Is it even possible in one query?

Comment: Create a procedure and you can use IF EXISTS..INSERT ELSE INSERT soemthingelse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need a row -- even if there are no matches -- think aggregation.  In your case:

```
INSERT INTO `links` (`url`, `url_hash`, `parent_id`)
    SELECT $url, MD5($url), max(id)
    FROM (SELECT id
          FROM `links`
          WHERE `url` = $parentUrl
          LIMIT 1
         ) t;
```

This will generate one row.  I'm not sure what "first" means in this context.  This will be an arbitrary row.  You need an `order by` to get one in a particular order.

I am also guessing that the expression `MD5(url)` should really be `MD5($url)`.

EDIT:

Not that it really makes much of a difference, but if you only want to reference `$url` once:

```
INSERT INTO `links` (`url`, `url_hash`, `parent_id`)
    SELECT url, MD5(url), max(id)
    FROM (SELECT id, $url as url
          FROM `links`
          WHERE `url` = $parentUrl
          LIMIT 1
         ) t;
```

Comment: Aww thanks! I wrote MD5(url) on purpose, this worked fine in my previous INSERT INTO VALUES statement. But you're right, it should be MD5($url) now, which makes me sad though. I don't want to send the same string twice to my SQL server. At INSERT INTO VALUES I could refer to the value written to the url field on the fly. I also don't want to create hashed by myself before sending to keep portability.